# Statement $\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca \ge 3$ is true for any positive $a$, $b$, $c$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let us have $a,b,c$ arbitrary positive numbers. Prove:

$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \ge 3$

I have tried many things, but none of them seemed to work. Any ideas? (If duplicate, I am sorry, didn't see it yet) :)

Comment: Counterexample $a=1,b=-1,c=1\implies a/b+b/c+c/a=-1-1+1<3$. $a,b,c$ must be of the same sign, I think.

Comment: $a,b,c$ of the same sign I think, consider $(a,b,c)=(1,-1,1)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I correct that.

Comment: See also: [Proving $\frac{x}{y} +\frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{x} \ge 3$ for positive $x,y,z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381673) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/381673).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Use [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) to get $$\frac{a/b+b/c+c/a}{3}\ge (a/b\cdot b/c\cdot c/a)^{1/3}=1$$

Comment: Wow, it is really that simple, thanks!