# Sum of fractions Inequality: $ {a\over b} + {b \over c} + {c \over a} \ge 3 $

Tags: inequality

Prove that:

$$ {a\over b} + {b \over c} + {c \over a} \ge 3 $$

Assuming $a, b, c > 0$. I was able to prove that this is true:

$$ {a\over b} + {b \over a} \ge 2 $$

by just rearranging it to get:

$$ a^2 + b^2 > 2ab $$

I figured if I would then repeat this with a,c and then b,c; I could sum the three inequalities to get closer to the third; so I get to:

$$ {a\over b} + {b \over c} + {c \over a} + {b\over a} + {c \over b} + {a \over c} \ge 6 $$

Now because of the symmetry; it certainly seems like the top inequality should be true; but I'm having trouble arguing past this point.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269415, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381673, and probably some more. (Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Ba%5Cover%20b%7D%20%2B%20%7Bb%20%5Cover%20c%7D%20%2B%20%7Bc%20%5Cover%20a%7D%20%5Cge%203%24&p=1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inequality between the arithmetic and the geometric mean, 
$$
\frac 13
\left(
\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca
\right)\ge
\left(
\frac ab\cdot\frac bc\cdot\frac ca
\right)^{1/3}
=1\ .
$$

Comment: Oh gosh... That should have been way more obvious than it was.

Answer (score 1):

Just use AM-GM:
$${a\over b} + {b \over c} + {c \over a} \ge 3\sqrt[3]{{a\over b}\cdot  {b \over c} \cdot  {c \over a}} = 3$$